# Nao Text-To-Speech on Choregraphe

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I am currently working with virtual nao on Choregraphe, I know it is not possible to use the ALTextToSpeech module on Choregraphe with virtual nao. Is there any way to use Nao's original text-to-speech module without using a physical robot?

Comment: No, I don't believe this is possible. What are you trying to achieve? To test your app with dialog interactions without access to a robot?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to test virtual Nao interactions and I need to access the original voice of Nao. But currently, I can't access to my Physical robot.

Comment: If it's just for development purposes - I'd suggest using another text to speech library to test with, even though it doesn't have the exact same voice. If you need it for some presentation purpose, I'd suggest pre-recording the dialog you need from the real NAO, and playing back the right lines when appropriate. To the best of my knowledge, NAO's text to speech implementation isn't open source, so can't be used when not on a real robot.